# Get data from selected checkboxes in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a form rawmaterial and in that I've a Gridview with checkboxcolumn and some form fields. I want to get all the fields of the selected rows as array.
I've tried to solve as mentioned here - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53777-gridview-get-selected-colum/. But getting Not Found error.
Code of index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Rmtemplate;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\rmprod\models\RmtemplateSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Templates';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="rmtemplate-index">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'rmtemplate-index',
        'action' => ['/rmprod/Rmtemplate/processSelected',],
        'method' => 'get',
        'enableClientScript' => false,

    ]); ?>

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'id'=>'mytable',
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

            //'id',
            //'productname',
            [
                'attribute'=>'productname',
                'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Rmtemplate::find()->orderBy(['productname' => SORT_ASC])->asArray()->all(), 'productname', 'productname'),
                'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true],
                                    ],
                'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Charge Name'],
            ],
            'rmname',
            'qty',
            // [
            //  'attribute' => 'unitcost',
            //  'value' => 'unitcost.unitcost',
            // ],
            'cost',

            //['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <div class="form-group pull-right">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Next', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary search','id'=>'tabbutton',]) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<?php
/* start getting the data */
$script = <<<EOD
$('tabbutton').one('click',function() {
    var keys = $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows'); // returns an array of pkeys, and #grid is your grid element id
    $.post({
       url: '/rmtemplate/processSelected', // your controller action
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {keylist: keys},
       success: function(data) {
          if (data.status === 'success') {
              alert('I did it! Processed checked rows.');
          }
       },
    });
});
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the data */
?>
```

Controller Action

```
public function actionProcessSelected() {
    if (isset($_POST['keylist'])) {
        $keys = \yii\helpers\Json::decode($_POST['keylist']);
        // you will have the array of pk ids to process in $keys
        // perform batch action on these keys and return status
        // back to ajax call above
        }
    }
```

Console
[image]

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the GridView like:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'id'=>'mytable',
   ...
```

And in your js code, call this:

```
var rows = $('#mytable').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

Comment: Hi gmc, I've tries your solution and also try to display the array as alert. But it's returning empty. I've updated the present code in the question. Also not sure why it's redirecting to create. I'm not calling create action anywhere till now.

Comment: The checked rows are then in the `rows` variable, which you do not use. Put `console.log(rows)` and check the js console, you'll see

Comment: use $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');  for the value.   and check following links also.it may help you                              http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53777-gridview-get-selected-colum/

Comment: Hi Rahul, I've tried as the link given by you. But not quite sure if I've implemented it correctly. I've updated my present code in the question. Please have a look and let me know how to get all the data as an array.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible(Temporary) soutions you can try:
        **Solution 1::**

```
In Index.php=>  
    //define action  ::  
    $productupdate = '/rmprod/Rmtemplate/processSelected';  
    In column add this........  
    [  
     'class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'  
     'checkboxOptions' => function ($data) {  
               return ['value' =>  $data['product_primary_key'], 'class' => 'class_checkbox'];  //primary_key=>product_primary_key
                        },  
    ],  
    Add Jquery code(To post data) ::::  
        $('.class_checkbox').change(function()  
        {  
            var action_url = '<?= $productupdate; ?>';  
            if (this.checked) {  
                var product_data = $(this).attr('value'); //get product_primary_key  
                $.ajax({  
                    method: "post",  
                    url: action_url,  
                    data: {product_data:product_data,_csrf: csrfToken}  
                }).done(function(data)  
                { 
                    $('#LoadingMSG').hide();  
                    console.log(data);  
                });  
            }
            else  
            {  
                //you can apply another ajax to post data when checkbox unselect  
            }  
        });  
    In Controller=>  
    public function processSelected()  
    {  
    $getdata = Yii::$app->request->post(); //get posted data   
    //apply query to play with database by $getdata (primary_key)  
    }
```

**Solution 2**

```
In Index.php.............  
    [  
     'class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'  
     'checkboxOptions' => function ($data) {  
               return ['value' =>  $value1.'+'.$value2.'+'.$value3.'+'.$value4, 'class' => 'class_checkbox']; 
                        },  
    ],   
    Add Jquery code(To post data) ::::  
        $('.class_checkbox').change(function()  
        {  
            var action_url = '<?= $productupdate; ?>';  
            if (this.checked) {  
                var all_flds_data = $(this).attr('value'); 
                $.ajax({  
                    method: "post",  
                    url: action_url,  
                    data: {all_flds_data:all_flds_data,_csrf: csrfToken}  
                }).done(function(data)  
                { 
                    $('#LoadingMSG').hide();  
                    console.log(data);  
                });  
            }
            else  
            {  
                //you can apply another ajax to post data when checkbox unselect  
            }  
        });  
In Controller=>  
    public function processSelected()  
    {  
    $getdata = Yii::$app->request->post(); //get posted data   
    //after json_deocode you will get all posted data from ajax  
    }
```

Comment: Would be much helpful if you can explain the solutions and the assumptions made for the same